# Calendar basic want to disable

Tags: settings

I keep getting calendar notifications that there are no events, no matter what I try I cannot disable the calendar. Tried settings a number of times no luck!!

Comment: What calendar are you using?

Comment: Also, what is the device model and Android version? Strange for a calendar app to notify that there's no event...

Comment: Are you using a particular fork/mod or is it just vanilla Android - in future try and include this stuff in your question

Comment: I am using vanilla android ver 4.2.2 and the calendar that comes with it. It is running on a Protoz tablet mod PT33032-7

Comment: After did some researching for ["You have no events scheduled today"](https://www.google.com.sg/webhp?#q=%22You+have+no+events+scheduled+today%22), I think it's related to Google Calendar web app, not Android Calendar app. Basically you're getting **email** notifications, but not app notifications. **Please clarify the source of notification**. Otherwise, this is off-topic and might be suitable on [webapps.se].

Answer (score 1):

go to Settings/Apps/All, select the Calendar you are talking about and uncheck "Show notifications."

Comment: This will help but will also disable potentially useful notifications for events that are actually happening